# Помогите с ошибкой No module named 'chardet'

Tags: python

Заранее говорю, что я посмотрел все возможные запросы по этой теме, но мне ничего не помогло.
Постоянно одна ошибка.
Вот код ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    import telebot
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from telebot import apihelper, types, util
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

Я не могу запустить не один файл который запускался ранее. В коде ничего не менял.
Пытался только установить aiogram.

**Module chardet уже существует**

**Requirement already satisfied: chardet in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (3.0.4)**

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй from charted import *

Comment: ничего не поменялось..